# Can agents see through field barrier doors?

Tags: evil-genius

One of the updates to the security door is the field barrier door - lasers shoot top to bottom. It's much stronger and harder to hack of the alternatives, but... it's not solid.

[image]

As such I'm worried that agents might able to "see through" the doors and acquire heat from items behind even before cracking the door open.

Can agents see through field barrier doors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, no.  Agents will still hack through them even if they lead to innocent places like your mess hall or pharmacy.

In fact, once I get newer door technologies, I tend to replace **all** my existing doors with the new ones, just so agents spend more time hacking through useless doors.

Comment: Yep, my new base is only going to have this kind of doors.

Answer (score 5):

In order to acquire heat from objects (rather than from being attacked), the agents take a picture of the incriminating object.  They certainly aren't using DSLRs, as they need to get within one tile of an object to trigger the animation.  This means that they can't gather heat from objects behind doors.

The startled "oh my goodness what's that? It appears to be nefarious!" animation can be triggered from a few tiles away but only within the same room and where the agent has a viable path to get to it, so again not through field barrier doors.

The viable path requirement means that the agent must be able to walk to within 1 tile without their path being obstructed in order to trigger the "gasp" animation and consequent heat production - for example during the base move my Ark of the Covenant Uber Loot became stuck in the corner of a strong room behind piles of impassable gold.  Despite several "exceptional" agents appearing to have a line of sight to the loot, they ignored it entirely as they had no way to get within one tile of it.

Therefore your ill gotten loot is entirely safe behind a field barrier door as long as the agents stay on the other side!